# Javascript - remove split method

Tags: javascript, split

I am trying to create the select application using Javascipt only. I got to know about this code on internet and it uses the split method to return value and .innerHTML. Now say if I do not want to use the split method and just return with .innerHTML into html element with no value, how to do that using for loop as used in this code ?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Select Options</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Choose your car</h2>
<hr>

Choose Car Make:
<select id="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai</option>
    <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
    <option value="Maruti">Maruti</option>
</select>

<hr>

Choose Car Model
<select id="slct2" ></select>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(s1,s2){
        var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
        var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
        s2.innerHTML = "";

        if(s1.value == "Hyundai") {
            var optionArray = ["|", "i10|i10","i20|i20", "Verna|Verna"]
        }
        for(var option in optionArray){
            var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
            var newOption = document.createElement('option');
            newOption.value = pair[0];
            newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
            s2.options.add(newOption);
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: so don't use the split method? Just set the innerHTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware, that using `for... in` loop over an array, won't return you the elements actually, but their indexes. I would suggest you to use simple `for` loop instead.

```js
function populate(s1, s2) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  
  var optionArray = ["i10", "i20", "Verna"];
    
  for (var i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
    var newOption = document.createElement('option');
    newOption.value = optionArray[i];
    newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[i];
    s2.appendChild(newOption);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Choose your car</h2>
<hr> Choose Car Make:
<select id="slct1" onchange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai</option>
    <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
    <option value="Maruti">Maruti</option>
</select>

<hr> Choose Car Model
<select id="slct2"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing or simply commenting (may be you would require it in future) few lines should do what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(s1,s2){
        var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
        var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
        s2.innerHTML = "";

        if(s1.value == "Hyundai") {
            var optionArray = ["|", "i10|i10","i20|i20", "Verna|Verna"]
        }
        for(var option in optionArray){
            var pair = optionArray[option]; //.split("|");
            var newOption = document.createElement('option');
            newOption.value = pair; //[0];
            newOption.innerHTML = pair; //[1];
            s2.options.add(newOption);
        }
    }
</script>
```

With above code, you are no using `.split()` and just assigning the whole object to the new element.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I got the code and it works really well. Thankyou for your time

Comment: If the above answer helped you. You may want to select it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Okay but I need some more help now

Comment: `function populate(s1,s2){
var s1,s2;
s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  if(s1.value=='Hyundai'){
   optionArray=['Please Select Car','i10','i20','Verna']
  } else
  if(s1.value=='Honda'){
   optionArray=['Please Select Car','Amaze','Jazz','City']
  } else
  if(s1.value=='Maruti'){
   optionArray=['Please Select Car','Swift','Dezire','Ciaze']
  } 
 for (var i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
  var store = optionArray[i];
  var createNewEl = document.createElement('option');
  createNewEl.innerHTML = store;
  s2.appendChild(createNewEl);}`

Comment: This is the full code I use now to write this apllication but I everytime I select option from **car make ** and when I select another option from**car make**, it does not delete the previous options from **car model** and the list gets increased so on everytime I select option from **car make**

Answer (score 1):

Left value to `""` to keep it empty.

```
for(var option in optionArray){
   var text = optionArray[option];
   var newOption = document.createElement('option');
   newOption.value = "";
   newOption.innerHTML = text;
   s2.options.add(newOption, null);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion bud ! I appreciate your time